# sqlite3 - update primary key on conflict

Tags: sqlite

I have a following table with name-value pairs.

```
CREATE TABLE settings (id integer primary key, name text unique, val integer);
```

`name` is unique. I'd like `id` to be incremented and `val` to be updated when there is a `name` conflict and `val` has changed. If the row has not changed (say, the same `name` and the `val`), `id` should remain unchanged.

Since we need to insert large number of rows at once, we need to use bulk insert (**mandatory**).

I tried using `insert or replace` but it seems to to be changing `id` even when the row is unchanged

```
sqlite> insert or replace into settings (name, val) values("name1", 1), ("name2", 20);
sqlite> select * from settings;
1|name1|1
2|name2|20
sqlite> insert or replace into settings (name, val) values("name1", 1), ("name2", 20);
sqlite> select * from settings;
3|name1|1
4|name2|20
```

I then tried to use on conflict

```
sqlite> insert into settings (name, val) values("name1", 88), ("name2", 6) on conflict do update set val=5, id=rowid+1;
sqlite> select * from settings;
1|name1|88
2|name2|6
sqlite> insert into settings (name, val) values("name1", 88), ("name2", 6) on conflict do update set val=5, id=rowid+1;
Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: settings.id
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: why would someone give negative point to this without any comment?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `CTE` will all the rows that you want to insert.
Instead of `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ... VALUES` use `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ... SELECT ...` with an `EXCEPT` clause that will exclude rows that already exist in the table and try to insert only rows with different `name` and/or `val`:

```
WITH cte(name, val) AS (VALUES ('name1', 1), ('name2', 20))
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO settings (name, val) 
SELECT name, val FROM cte
EXCEPT
SELECT name, val FROM settings
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=76c5d5638a7197cd3a18998a50f97848).